# Access Jupyter Lab running on VPS from internet via browser

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, jupyter-lab

On a VPS I ran a dockerized Jupyter Lab that itself driven from project [freqtrade](https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade).
It is the docker-compose and Dockerfile :
docker-compose.yml :

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  ft_jupyterlab:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.jupyter
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: ft_jupyterlab
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Default command used when running `docker compose up`
    command: >
      jupyter lab --port=8888 --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=''
```

Dockerfile.jupyter :

```
FROM freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop_plot

# Pin prompt-toolkit to avoid questionary version conflict
RUN pip install jupyterlab "prompt-toolkit<=3.0.36" jupyter-client --user --no-cache-dir

# Empty the ENTRYPOINT to allow all commands
ENTRYPOINT []
```

I want to access the Jupyter Lab from the internet via browser. So, I used Nginx as below:

```
server {
    listen 7000;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Suppose that `test.example.com` is pointed to <vps_ip> . By navigating to `http://test.example.com:7000` from another machine, just the title of "JupyterLab" shown. No any contents rendered in browser.

Also it is log:

```
[I 2024-02-06 06:18:07.626 ServerApp] 302 GET / (@172.27.0.1) 0.63ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In docker-compose file in sections port mapping, `127.0.0.1` must be removed.

```
ports:
  - "8888:8888"
```

so, the JupyterLab is accessible through http://<vps_ip>:8888 (without Nginx reverse proxy), but still the way using Nginx (http://<vps_ip>:7000) doesn't work. The log is mentioned at the end of my main post.